# SHMMAX / SHMALL Kernel parameters for postgres database with huge_pages on

Tags: postgresql, linux-kernel, database-administration, postgres-10

I've upgraded RAM on postgres server from 8 to 16 GB and set shared_buffer to 4GB. I'm also set

```
vm.nr_hugepages = 2300
```

calculated by [postgres doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/kernel-resources.html)

```
kernel.shmmax = 8589934592 (8GB)
```

Postgres is configured to use huge_page (`huge_page = 'on'`) with:

```sh
  grep -i hugepages /proc/meminfo
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:    2300
HugePages_Free:      167
HugePages_Rsvd:        4
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
```

What's the correct configuration of **kernel.shmall** ?

According to doc `kernel.shmall` is espressed in number of PAGE memory (getconf PAGE_SIZE--> 4096) but Hugepagesize:2048 kb. Current configuration is `kernel.shmall=4096` considering PAGE size 2048 kb but I'm not sure that is correct. Can you help me to understand this configuration please and if something is wrong. To setting `kernel.shmall` I must  consider `PAGE size = 2048 kb` or `PAGE size = 4096 byte`? And what's the best configuration of these parameters?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL v10 uses POSIX shared memory unless you set `shared_memory_type = sysv`, so the System V shared memory kernel parameters are irrelevant, and you don't have to tune them.

Comment: thanks Laurenz, just out of curiosity in case we have postgres version prior to PostgreSQL 9.3, what's correct page size that should be considered ?

Comment: I don't know, but I'd just set it crazy high. It is only a limit.